# Regex for Cisco's "show run interface" command

Tags: regex

Please help me to write a regex that will match everything that starts with "interface bundle-ether" and ends with "!" Like for this output

```
show run interface bundle-ether1

Tue Jan 20 21:30:28.125 PDT
interface Bundle-Ether1
 description 
 service-policy
 service-policy 
 ipv4 address 
 encapsulation
!

RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:device.name#
show run interface bundle-ether2

Tue Jan 20 21:30:28.394 PDT
interface Bundle-Ether2
 description 
 service-policy 
 service-policy
 ipv4 address 
 encapsulation
!

RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:device.name#
show run interface bundle-ether3

Tue Jan 20 21:30:28.674 PDT
interface Bundle-Ether3
 description
 service-policy
 service-policy
 ipv4 address
 encapsulation
!
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this regex does the magic :)

```
interface Bundle\s*(?<text>[^!])+(?:!)?
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
interface Bundle-Ether[^!]*!
```

`[^!]*` matches any sequence of characters that aren't `!`.